# Can I use LWJGL 3 with OpenGL 1.4?

Tags: java, lwjgl

Today I saw a couple of tutorials that talked about the java library called [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org). Most of the people who created these tutorials used [OpenGL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) 2.0, since I have OpenGL 1.4 my question as you can read from the title was if I could use LWJGL with OpenGL 1.4.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: When I put: ContextAttribs contextAttributes = new ContextAttribs(1, 4) he says: Illegal OpenGL version.

Comment: Code example here: wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Version_selection.html

Comment: LWJGL has classes for OpenGL under 2.0. So Yes, you can use LWJGL with OpenGL 1.4. Use `GL14`